# How do i construct my models and my parsing with JSON Decoder using Swift code 4

Tags: json, swift4

I have this JSON response that i need decoded on Swift 4 but i only need certain properties from it. I want to grab only the Game EventTypes and register only the timestamp,legendPlayed,gameLength And the “Kills” in number if it exists under the game event. So in total i want timestamp,legendPlayed,gameLength and kills(if they exist) from the games only not sessions or levels or whatever else. How do i construct my models and my parsing with JSON Decoder?

```
[
   {
       "uid": "6774478804953216437",
       "player": "Yungblem6",
       "timestamp": 1598780938,
       "eventType": "Session",
       "event": {
           "action": "join"
       }
   },
   {
       "uid": "6774478804953216437",
       "player": "Yungblem6",
       "timestamp": 1598778237,
       "eventType": "Session",
       "event": {
           "action": "leave",
           "sessionDuration": 174
       }
   },
   {
       "uid": "6774478804953216437",
       "player": "Yungblem6",
       "timestamp": 1598777637,
       "eventType": "Level",
       "event": {
           "newLevel": 182
       }
   },
   {
       "uid": "6774478804953216437",
       "player": "Yungblem6",
       "timestamp": 1598777637,
       "eventType": "Game",
       "xpProgress": 0,
       "gameLength": 10,
       "legendPlayed": "Wraith",
       "rankScoreChange": "0",
       "event": []
   },
   {
       "uid": "6774478804953216437",
       "player": "Yungblem6",
       "timestamp": 1598776978,
       "eventType": "Game",
       "xpProgress": 2880,
       "gameLength": 12,
       "legendPlayed": "Wraith",
       "rankScoreChange": "0",
       "event": [
           {
               "value": 3,
               "key": "kills",
               "name": "Kills"
           }
       ]
   },
   {
       "uid": "6774478804953216437",
       "player": "Yungblem6",
       "timestamp": 1598776198,
       "eventType": "Game",
       "xpProgress": 360,
       "gameLength": 2,
       "legendPlayed": "Wraith",
       "rankScoreChange": "0",
       "event": [
           {
               "value": 1,
               "key": "kills",
               "name": "Kills"
           }
       ]
   },
   {
       "uid": "6774478804953216437",
       "player": "Yungblem6",
       "timestamp": 1598767798,
       "eventType": "Session",
       "event": {
           "action": "join"
       }
   },
   {
       "uid": "6774478804953216437",
       "player": "Yungblem6",
       "timestamp": 1598767737,
       "eventType": "Game",
       "xpProgress": 4680,
       "gameLength": 24,
       "legendPlayed": "Wraith",
       "rankScoreChange": "0",
       "event": [
           {
               "value": 4,
               "key": "kills",
               "name": "Kills"
           }
       ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    struct Player: Codable {
    var uid: String
    var player: String
    var timestamp: String
    var eventType: String
    var event: Event
    
}

struct Event: Codable {
    var event: String
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.